# What is the best verb to use when talking about going after someone (to pick them from home, etc.)?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

I am looking for a verb either one-part or two-part, to describe going after someone for example your mom to take them from home for example on your car. First I wanted to use *come after*, but it seems it has a negative implication like hurting someone. Also, *go after* seems to mean following and chasing someone rather than going to pick them. What is the best verb to use here?

An example of how I want to use it is as follows:

> ---
>
> -Were not you supposed to **come after me** in the morning so we would not get stuck in traffic?
>    - That's right. Sorry mom for being late. The road will open now and we will go.

Comment: Most people would say **"pick them up"** I think, or "pick me up" in your example sentence.

Comment: Actually your grammar is quite confusing:  are you talking about "transporting your mom from your house to the station" for example, or the other way round?

Comment: Yes, @MaxWilliams transporting mom from home to a station, shopping center, etc.

Comment: related: ['Pick' as an alternative for 'pick up' (transport)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69187/pick-as-an-alternative-for-pick-up-transport).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your example sentences below, to better reflect the intended meaning I think you wanted, let me know if anything is unclear, or if I've misunderstood your question...

As you have asked for a one, or two form verb, I'd suggest the following: -

> Were you not supposed to collect me this morning to avoid us
>   getting stuck in this traffic?
>   
>   That's right. Sorry I was late mom. The traffic will clear soon,
>   and we will be on our way.

Other possibilities are..

"Were you not supposed to come and **get** me..."

You mentioned one or two part verbs, but just for clarification, this is a more typical phrase: -

"Were you not supposed to come and **pick me up**"

Comment: Thank you, you not only answered my question, but also edited my example to a much better form.

Comment: My pleasure, pleased I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Were not you supposed to ***[fetch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fetch)*** me in the morning?

> Go for and then bring back (someone or something) for someone:
> *he ran to fetch help*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fetch

Answer (score 0):

This question has been on my mind for such a long time. What if here JasonStack is not going to pick up her mom with a car? I mean, what should we say if he is on foot and is going after his mom to go somewhere together? Can we say it like this:

When I have a car: Mom, I will come to pick you up at 7:00 pm.
When I don't have a car (I'm on foot): Mom, I will come after you at 7:00 pm.

Is there any difference between the two? Or can the second one be used in the first case, too?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "come for" rather than "come after".