# To collect someone from or to pick someone from?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-usage

What is more natural to say: *To collect someone from reception* (airport, train station, waiting room) or to *pick someone from reception*?
Or is there something more appropriate?

What would a receptionist say to someone having an appointment:
*"Please, take a seat; someone from company ABC is on the way to collect (?) you"*.
I heard that sentence so many times, and still, it's hard to believe, I cannot remember what the phrase is!?

Collect is typically used to collect a thing: a parcel from a post office. Could it also apply to humans?

To pick has several unwanted connotations too: to pick a girl, to pick *on* someone, to pick a target (sniping in game) etc..

Comment: As Jeff Zeitlin points out, it's *never* 'pick someone from...', but 'pick someone **up** from...'

Comment: Addressed at  ['pick' as an alternative for 'pick up' (transport)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69187/pick-as-an-alternative-for-pick-up-transport)

Comment: *Collect* is fine.  It's probably more common in British English countries than American English countries but idiomatic in either.  *Collect* also sounds to my ear more proper and formal, while *pick up* is, as you note, more informal, though either is fine in this usage.

Comment: I almost think we might *collect* someone when that's the reason for the journey and *pick up* the same person en route to something else.

I just added at Edwin's handy link, above, that I've met several South Africans and dozens of Zimbabweans who never use *pick up*; always *pick*. My acquaintances happen all to have English as a second language, after Shona, Sindebele or Zulu.

Comment: @Edwin regarding the potential duplicity, my question was about which of the phrases is more idiomatic, pick *up* from  - marcellothearcane thanks for the correction - was just one of the possibilities.

Comment: @FlaviusIulianus I hope no one here is is telling lies; perhaps you mean 'duplication' instead of 'duplicity'.

Comment: The previous question addresses the idiomaticity – indeed, the correctness – of 'pick someone from the station'. ODO, for instance, gives an example licensing 'collect the children from the station'.

Comment: @ Mark Beadles  sorry, I indeed meant "duplication" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Collect" is not incorrect, but it's not the usual usage in most of the US, to the best of my knowledge. There are other idioms that are more common, depending on context:

- **Pick up** is often used if you are waiting for someone who will be providing transportation to a different location - for example, "John will come **pick** you **up** when your train arrives".
- **Get** is also used in the general context, as in your example above: "Someone from Human Resources will come **get** you when they're ready to interview you."

The usage of "collect" in similar contexts that I've heard has almost universally been when there were a group of people together for a purpose, e.g., waiting for a tour to begin - "Please wait here; your guide will be here shortly to collect you."