# To collect someone or to pick someone - UK English

Tags: idioms, british-english

What would a receptionist say to someone having an appointment:
"Please, take a seat; someone from company ABC is on the way to collect (?) you".

What is more more idiomatic in a formal UK English: To collect someone from reception (airport, train station, waiting room) or to pick someone from reception? Or is there something more appropriate?

Linked to: [To collect someone from or to pick someone from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399442/to-collect-someone-from-or-to-pick-someone-from) where it is nicely answered for US English.

Comment: If someone is ***picking you up*** in such contexts, the implication is usually that they will "transport" you (often, by car) to wherever you need to go. If all they're doing is *meeting and greeting* you, and *guiding* you somewhere within an office building, ***collect*** is the better choice.

Comment: But personally, I think a well-trained receptionist would more likely use ***meet*** rather than ***collect***. It's a bit "dehumanising" when what's being collected is actually the person being addressed - that's more like something she might say if you'd brought in a parcel that needed to be delivered *in person* to a manager within the company.

Comment: Meet. Yes, that's much nicer, I agree. Problem is, the person collecting you is not necessary a person you are going to meet, they can be someone literally showing you the, way, a junior employee; taking you through security, looking after you before the relevant person to meet really comes to meet you.

Comment: If they are showing you the way, they will certainly have to meet you to do this. "Meet" doesn't necessarily mean anything stronger than this.

Comment: FlaviusIulianus: That's just being pedantic, and I really don't think any native speakers would bother about the distinction between a "company representative, office junior" who meets you at the reception desk in order to take you to your business meeting, and the (boss?!) man you meet there. But if you *were* that pedantic boss, you could always tell the receptionist to say *Someone is coming **to escort you to your meeting***.

Comment: There are so many ways the same notion could be expressed. For example, Someone might come to bring you back or bring you in to the meeting or bring you to the office. These could be used in either American or British English. "Collect" an exclusively British choice for this context.

Answer (score 2):

I heard it yesterday, straight from the horse's mouth, from a UK native speaker receptionist, laud and clear:

*Someone is on the way down to collect you.*

Also, couple of days before, one the first round of my interview, she also used this simplified version:

*Someone is on the way down for you.*

..useful in case you want to bypass the dilemma.

Sorry for posting a very similar question, but my original was incorrectly marked as duplicate so no additional answers cannot be posted. Sorry for posting and instantly answering it, but I believe it's a valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

In Great Britain, *coming to collect you* is common. In the U.S., we'd usually say *coming to get you* or *coming down/up/over/out for you*.

No one would say *company ABC* in either country. We'd just say the company name. We wouldn't say *company* first.